# quarkus myfaces jsf extension native javax.faces.FacesException - Bean Validation is not present

Tags: jsf, quarkus, myfaces

I can't use the native validator with quarkus and myfaces jsf extension

I have a class of type @Entity with the annotation on a @NotEmpty field

```
@Entity
public class Product extends PanacheEntity{
    
    @NotEmpty
    public String sku;
        
}
```

i have an product.xhtml view with an h: form

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{cart.current.sku}" />
    <h:commandButton actionListener="#{cart.save()}" />
</h:form>
```

I have a class of type @ViewScoped @Named

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class Cart implements Serializable {

    @Setter @Getter
    private Product current = new Product();
        
    public void save () {
        System.out.println ("org.acme.getting.Cart.save () ********");
    }
    
}
```

compiled in native I get the following error

```
An Error Occurred:
Bean Validation is not present

viewId = / product.xhtml
location = null
phaseId = PROCESS_VALIDATIONS (3)

Caused by:
javax.faces.FacesException - Bean Validation is not present
at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.createValidatorFactory (BeanValidator.java:329)

javax.faces.FacesException: Bean Validation is not present
    at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.createValidatorFactory(BeanValidator.java:329)
    at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:186)
    at org.apache.myfaces.core.api.shared.ComponentUtils.callValidators(ComponentUtils.java:245)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:472)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:729)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:302)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:204)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1410)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1410)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._processValidatorsDefault(UIViewRoot.java:1759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.access$500(UIViewRoot.java:83)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ProcessValidatorPhaseProcessor.process(UIViewRoot.java:1867)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1715)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:965)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsExecutor.execute(ProcessValidationsExecutor.java:39)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:125)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:207)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:65)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:111)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:589)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:152)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$1.handleRequest(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:119)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:290)
    at io.undertow.server.DefaultExchangeHandler.handle(DefaultExchangeHandler.java:18)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$5$1.run(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:415)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:519)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
```

what can it depend on?
how can I solve it, it normally works, when I compile it with Graalvm in native and start it I get the error indicated, removing the @NotEmpty validator it also works in native.

this is my pom configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dolce</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.1.4.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.adminfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your pom file or gradle build ?

Comment: file pom loaded

Comment: Can you upgrade your quarkus version to 2.2.2.Final, there was an issue related to the hiberante validator in the 2.1.x, just to exclude this posibility. Also you are using a library for faces that does not belong to the quarkus project, I suggest you to try to create an empty project with this library and quarkus to check if everything works fine or other case also opening an issue to the library owner he might have an idea of what is happening or where to look